# JavaFx include multiple gui in the main gui

Tags: javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I have a main gui in fxml file created with SceneBuilder and its related controller.
In that main gui I've a gridpane where I want to put, for each cell, three child (a label, a TextView and a CheckBox).
So I've created an additional fxml with an HBox as root and the three childs.

Now... How could I add by code in the gridpane of the main gui the defined component for each cell and interacts with them?

I mean... what I want to do is something like this in the main gui controller:

for (int i)
for (int j)
gridpane.add("the_composed_view_in_the_other_fxml", i, j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would do something like this in the `initialize` method of your "main" controller:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private GridPane gridpane ;

    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        int numCols = ... ;
        int numRows = ... ;

        for (int rowIndex = 0 ; rowIndex < numRows ; rowIndex++) {
            for (int colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < numCols ; colIndex++) {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/addtional/fxml"));
                gridpane.add(loader.load(), colIndex, rowIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For "interacting" with the components loaded from the additional fxml file, it is really the responsibility of the controller for the additional fxml. You can get a reference to each of those controllers after you load the fxml file:

```
gridpane.add(loader.load(), colIndex, rowIndex);
AdditionalController controller = loader.getController();
```

and then you can call methods that you have defined in that controller class. You haven't really provided enough detail about what you might want to do here, but, e.g.:

```
public class AdditionalController {

    @FXML
    private CheckBox checkBox ;

    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return checkBox.selectedProperty();
    }

    // etc...
}
```

and then something like

```
gridpane.add(loader.load(), colIndex, rowIndex);
AdditionalController controller = loader.getController();

String s = String.format("Item [%d, %d]", colIndex, rowIndex);
controller.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
    if (isNowSelected) {
        // process selection...
        System.out.println(s + " is selected");
    }
});
```